# ASP.NET SSRS ReportViewer parameters not sticking

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm just getting into adding SSRS ReportViewer to an ASP.NET website project. I have the report displaying but the parameters cascade and thus refresh the parameters that follow.

When the page refreshes the value that was just selected and triggered the page to refresh doesn't stick and comes back empty, as though I hadn't selected anything.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the initialization in an IsPostBack check